# Cannot access ProductName registry value in Windows Sandbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-sandbox

I am trying to get the OS information from registry through ProductName key in HKLM\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion but it does not seem to be present in my C# application in Windows Sandbox. However, when I check the registry value by manually opening the `regedit`, it is present.

Are there any possible solutions for this?

I have tried getting information through following code:

```
  var registry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
  string productName = registry.GetValue("ProductName").ToString();
```

`registry.GetValue("ProductName")` seems to be null but it is present when I manually open the registry editor.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out.

In x64 systems, Registry key is accessed from `HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node`. `ProductName` was not present there, hence I was unable to access the value.